# Run wordpress plugin on Joomla based website

Tags: wordpress, iframe, joomla, wordpress-theming, joomla-template

I have a question related to the WordPress<>Joomla compatibility. Recently I purchased a sophisticated plugin which runs on WordPress only. But my website with all the content and the design is based on Joomla. So I'm trying to figure out the means how I could use that WordPress plugin on the Joomla website. As I said before it's kind of advanced plugin with many options, so I guess it would be difficult to adapt the code to fit Joomla requirements. So I'm thinking about two possible solutions:

1. I could create a WordPress website with the same design that Joomla website has. However this solution requires to change all the Joomla template files, or to build the WordPress theme from scratch. Does anybody know any tutorial which explains how to migrate the template from Joomla to WordPress? I basically don't need to move the content, only the design. All the menu links and other stuff would redirect to the parent Joomla site.
2. The second solution I think would be to install the WordPress with that plugin on the server and then to create a copy of the Joomla site on the sub-domain. Then maybe I can use something like iframe on the Joomla site to show the WordPress plugin running. Is that kind of scenario possible? What kind of solution would you suggest? As I said before, I will keep my Joomla site anyway, because its already running with tons of data. I just need the functionality of one additional plugin, which sadly runs only on WordPress.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is doing the plugin exactly?

Comment: Would the user need to be logged in to use the plugin?

Comment: Haven't you found any similar plugin for Joomla? I can help with that, but I agree on @itoctopus, both options are bad.

Comment: The plugin allows to design your own credit card. To put the name on it, change font, size, position of text, backgrounds and etc. I dont know if there's any similar plugins for joomla. But anyway, it was already payed for that stuff, so I dont believe that they are going to pay again. The login is not necesarry for plugin to work. After you create your business card, the user save it to pdf and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Both scenarios are not practical - with the second being not feasible. What I recommend is that you adapt the WordPress plugin to Joomla or maybe search for a similar plugin that already exists on Joomla.

Comment: Why do you think the second scenario is not feasible? I think that should work. I would have a copy of the joomla site or even simple page of the joomla with the iframe and in that frame i would show the specific part of the other wordpress page with the plugin running. Adapting the plugin might be a little bit difficult since its not some kind of free plugin. It was bought from the developed and it works on wordpress and opencart only.